# Can one get rid of trigonometric functions in an expression like $\arccos{\frac{1}{ \sqrt{1 + \cos^2 \alpha}}}$?

Tags: trigonometry

Solving an engineering problem, I arrived to a formula $\beta = \arccos {\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \cos ^2 \alpha}}}$. Can this expression be simplified so as to get rid of trigonometric functions and their inverses?

Edit: I made a mistake somewhere along the way, so the formula ended up defined almost nowhere. I fixed it, and the formula is defined everywhere now. Specifically, as $\cos^2 \alpha \ge 1$, the value under $\arccos$ always $\in [0,1]$.

Now, after I fixed the formula, it seems I can apply 
$\cos \circ \arctan(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ to get $\beta = \arctan \circ \cos (\alpha)$ which would have a nice geometric meaning. But I'm really poor at trigonometry, so I'm not sure. Could someone second?

Comment: But $\arccos\sqrt{1+\cos^2\alpha}$ is nowhere defined

Comment: @KennyLau It is almost nowhere defined, but welldefined for $\alpha\in\left\{\frac12\pi,\frac32\pi\right\}$

Comment: @KennyLau Thank you. It is a silly error on my side.

Comment: Your formula can be reduced to $\cos^2(\alpha)=\tan^2(\beta)$, but not sure if that really helps.

Comment: $\tan ^{-1}(|\cos (a)|)$ should be OK

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that $\arccos$ is just defined on $[-1,1]$, so your formula
$\beta=\arccos\sqrt{1+\cos^2(\alpha)}$ is defined if and only if $\cos(\alpha)=0$ which is gives you the angle $\alpha=\frac12\pi$ or $\alpha=\frac32\pi$. But in that cases, you get $\beta=\arccos(1)=0$.

Otherwise, you have to check your formula. You might get the equation 
$$
\cos^2(\beta)=1+\cos^2(\alpha)
$$
and deduced the formula? But from this equation, you see that the RHS is greater or equal $1$ while the LHS is less or equation $1$. The equation can just be true if $\beta\in\left\{0,\pi\right\}$ and $\alpha\in\left\{\frac12\pi,\frac32\pi\right\}$. Here you see that you also got $\beta=\pi$ which the formula drops.